# How to remove a bash command which has been placed as docker?

Tags: bash, macos

There is a fake docker placed in my system (MacOS Big Sur) which I can't easily remove.
When I type docker --help in my terminal it says:

```
Options:
 -V, --version                output the version number
-i, --input_dir [dir]        Input directory (defaults to current dir) (default: 
"/Users/djsicrip")
-o, --output_dir [dir]       Output directory (defaults to ./doc) (default: 
 "/Users/djsicrip/doc")
 -u, --updated_files          Only process files that have been changed
-c, --colour_scheme [style]  Colour scheme to use (see 
 https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/tree/master/src/styles)
-I, --ignore_hidden          Ignore hidden files and directories (those starting with . 
 or _)
-w, --watch                  Watch on the input directory for file changes 
(experimental)
-s, --sidebar [state]        Whether the sidebar should be open or not by default 
(default: "yes")
-x, --exclude [pattern]      Paths to exclude (default: false)
-n, --line-numbers           Whether to include line numbers in output
-m, --multi_line_only        Whether to process only multi-line comments
--js <files>                 Additional javascript files to include
--css <files>                Additional CSS files to include
--extras <extras>            Bundled extras to include, see extras dir
-h, --help                   output usage information
```

When I type in docker --version it says 1.0.0

So question is how I can remove that docker command?

Comment: Also when I list all my terminal comands with "double esc": docker      postconf
docker.js                             postdrop

Comment: What does `type docker` say?

Comment: it says: docker is /Users/djsicrip/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/bin/docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [this project](https://jbt.github.io/docker/README.md.html), which is also called Docker but completely unrelated to Docker Engine:

> A documentation generator built on the foundations of Docco and Docco-Husky.

Probably you can use `npm uninstall -g docker` to get rid of it.